# jQuery .on() function on click event

Tags: jquery

I have some DIVs inserted by jQuery.
The structure is like this:

```
<div class="preview_images" id="preview_upload">
     <div class="image_box" id="img_box8793">
         <p>
            <img class="count_19" src="[...]">
            <br>
             <span class="del_img">löschen</span>
         </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

I want to use the on() function, before I used live().
This is my jQuery function:

```
$('#preview_upload div p').on("click", "span", function () {
    alert('###');
    parent_div_id = $(this).parent().parent('div').attr('id');
    $(this).parent().parent('div').fadeOut('slow');
    $('#final_img_prev #' + parent_div_id).remove();
    del_val = $(this).attr('title');
    $('#customfields-tf-150-tf,#customfields-tf-16-tf, #customfields-tf-17-tf, #customfields-tf-18-tf, #customfields-tf-19-tf').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == del_val) {
            $(this).val('');
            var img_count = jQuery.cookie('img_count');
            new_img_count = parseInt(img_count) - 1;
            if (new_img_count > 0) {
                jQuery.cookie('img_count', '', {
                    expires: -1
                });
                jQuery.cookie('img_count', new_img_count, {
                    expires: 1
                });
                if (new_img_count < 4) {
                    new_file = '<input type="file" id="file1" name="file1">';
                    $('#uploadForm .file_box').html('');
                    $('#uploadForm .file_box').html(new_file);
                    $('#uploadForm').fadeIn();
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

The alert() is not getting fired.

Where is the error?

**EDIT:**

This is my code after your answers:

```
jQuery(function($){
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#preview_upload div p').on("click", "span", function(){
            alert('###');
      });
   });
)};
```

I am using Jquery 1.7.2. Firebug shows no errros. No alert() is fired.

Maybe it is, because the DIVs and their contents are created dynamically?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: are you inserting different divs with the same id? (preview_upload)

Comment: Is there a reason your (document).ready is inside the parent function? I don't think it should be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `on` is used the event should be delegated from one of static parents of the element, the div `#preview_upload` is generated dynamically, so you should select another element like the `body` or `document` object for delegating the event, try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#preview_upload span", function(){
   // ..
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap this code in the document `ready` event and it works fine

```
$(function(){

   $('#preview_upload div p').on("click", "span", function(){
       alert("working")   
      //your code

   });

});
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/HBunv/

If that does not work, check for other script errors in your page. Firebug console will be helpful to figureout what is the script error

Answer (score 0):

I think you either have an outdated version of jQuery (lower than 1.7) or you run your code before content is loaded to the DOM, which means you need `$(document).ready(function()`.

Your code is working fine in the example below, and alert is firing!

Please check the working [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/rostovtsev/9cDnn/1/).

Comment: you must remove your `jQuery(function($){` on top and in the end remove `});`and it works, look example http://jsfiddle.net/rostovtsev/CTjDv/

Comment: You might also have a conflict in your code with other frameworks, try to use jQuery no conflict mode, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rostovtsev/2ZVM3/